# Is there a way to run Python's subprocess.check_output without the cwd to be the same directory as the exe being called

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to automate some tasks - the process requires I call some exe's and pass parameters.  The particular directories for the exe's are in the PATH variable for windows.  However, I consistently get a

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

My current workaround is to set the os.cwd to the directory with the exe but that imposes some other limits on how we distribute the code.  I want to note that in every case if I start a cmd window and type the same code I am passing to subprocess.check_output the code works no matter what directory I am in on the computer.

Just to be clear I am afraid for example of trying to automate a WinRAR task and WinRAR.exe is in a different folder on their computer.

Okay in response to the comment below here is the input and the output after I changed the cwd to root (c:)

The call to subprocess

```
rarProcess = check_output('''WinRAR a -r -v700m -sfx -agYYYYMMDD-NN -iiconD:\\RarResources\\de96.ico -iimgd:\\RarResources\\accounting2013.bmp d:\\testFTP\\compressed_test_ d:\\files_to_compress''')
```

and here is the Traceback message in all of it's glory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#93>", line 1, in <module>
rarProcess = check_output('''WinRAR a -r -v700m -sfx -agYYYYMMDD-NN -iiconD:\\RarResources\\de96.ico -iimgd:\\RarResources\\accounting2013.bmp d:\\testFTP\\compressed_test_ d:\\files_to_compress''')
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Now I can't prove that this is not a hypothetical question/problem.  I get the intended results when I use the same command (adjusting for path separators) through the cmd window and if I change the directory to the directory with the exe before running the command as pasted above.

Comment: Check out this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658622/python-subprocess-popen-environment-path) or this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679466/subprocess-call-or-subprocess-popen-cannot-use-executables-that-are-in-path-lin)

Comment: Please show an actual code example, with its intended behaviour and actual output, rather than describe a hypothetical problem. I suspect that you have issues with files in other directories because you are not quoting the `\\` character properly in during literals.

Comment: `help(subprocess.check_output)` refers you to Popen. `help(subprocess.Popen)` tells you about the cwd parameter. People around here tend to get grumpy if you don't check help first.

Comment: Well I did try help check_output and I don't see anything that guided me.  Thanks but it was not helpful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set os.cwd and run the process. Instead you pass the location of your   "Winrar.exe" file to the subprocess as a dict.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, env={'PATH': '/path/to/winrar.exe'})
```

Comment: Thanks I marked this as useful but it is not the answer I need because I might not know the path to the exe that I need, all I know is that the path is going to be one of the environment variables.